# responsiveness is not triggered when wrapped in a hybrid app

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, responsive-design

I have a website which uses bootstrap for responsiveness.

I tried to use Android phone to open this website in mobile browser, all UI components work fine, grids get re-located to fit the right size of screen.

I then wrap all the html code and related resources into a cordova project, everything works fine except the responsiveness. So the problem is the responsiveness isn't triggered in this hybrid app so all UI components stay where they are as they are displayed in a computer browser.

Do you have any ideas about this issue?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**

Here is my viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Comment: how is your `viewport` configured? I use this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">` in all of my apps. it would affect sizing of the view if not set

Comment: hi @DawsonLoudon thx for reply. I have updated my question to include my viewport. I haven't found anything different.